# How to make it so that the database is not visible when app is installed?

Tags: c#, .net

I started creating my own application in c# using Microsoft Access as a database. The problem is after I created my .exe file using this software I found on the internet, when Installed, the database is always accessible in c drive. Should I use different databases instead? enlighten me, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by visible, and why does it matter?

Comment: What's the nature of the data in the database?

Comment: If the database is accessible in c drive, the creation of the software becomes meaningless because somebody can just manipulate the data inside it instead of using the software itself. Is there a way to hide the database?

Comment: @Jezer are you shipping the db with the software or creating it dynamically?

Comment: No matter what you try, if the database is local, there is a way to access it. If this is such super-critical/confidential data, re-think your concept.

Comment: @HMZ sorry, I don't know what shipping means. But when I created the executable file, I just add all the files needed such as images and database.

Comment: @KlausGütter do you mean I should try and use different database instead?

Comment: @Jezer We don't know what type of solution you're writing but the idea is that even with password protecting your access db it's pretty useless and easily crackable.
Your only option for local security is encryption and its has a significant performance toll because you would be encrypting and decrypting on reads and writes.

Comment: @HMZ Even encryption would not really help as the key needs to be known to the app and therefore be present on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

- Place the database in a difficult to find location such as `AppData`
- Use the password/encryption features of Access; limited and crackable
- Encrypt the data in the database, which has the limitations mentioned by @HMZ
- Use an online database

You can either make it difficult to find and access the data or, if you need a fully secure database, use encryption or an online database. With an online database you will then need to host it and probably cope with multi-user access.

You need to understand the risks of each solution and decide accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your software is a  WinForm /WPF or any program that create with a programming  language such like C#  , then  the database doesn't has to be in `C` drive, because it is the programming  language to control that how to connect to the access database (normaly :  `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<your .accdb file location>` , and also you can use password for it ,  to hide it , you can rename the `.accdb` to `.dll` , then no-one will know it is a access database, also you can add a password )